# Base value in column on id but constrained to not-null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want to generate a value in a column based on the database ID ActiveRecord assigns to my record. Normally, I would just add an after save callback where this value is generated and than saved to the database.

Unfortunately,  I have to deal with a not-null constraint on that column, so it needs to be assigned at the same time when I get an ID. Is there a thread-safe way, to combine both?

Comment: You could set it to `''` or `0` (depending on the column type) when you create the record and then use an `after_save` callback.

Comment: When you rake db:migrate, rake will invoke a db transaction that will run in the background. The ID is determined during this transaction. This involves  tinkering with the ActiveRecord::Migration class. That is because when you rails g migration you are creating a migration that inherits from the aforementioned class. You can check rails project on github to see the inner-wrokings of activerecord https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb

Comment: I personally believe that @Jordan 's answer is the best solution.

Comment: Does this really need to be a column? If it is a fixed function of the row's `id` then why store it at all? Why not generate it when you need to show it to someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your code in transaction block, where you first find the maximum value of **id** column in the given table and than use that ID value to generate value of other column. Will that work for you?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  id = maximum(:id)
  other_column = "#{id} some string"
  create(other_column: other_column)
end
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `maximum(:id)` won't change before you call `create`.